# How to run pushbutton callback outside of GUI in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I have GUI-A with `pushbuton_callback` that calculates the user input and display in GUI-A. Now, how can I run GUI-B that execute GUI-A pushbutton ? Or is there any way to tell the computer to click the GUI-A pushbutton in GUI-B?

I have tried a command like:

```
GUI-A('pushbutton_Callback',handles.pushbutton,[], handles).
```

But it pops up error that "handles are not defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access handles, I use

```
h = guihandles(figure_handle);
```

This will store all handles associated with *figure_handle* in a structure *h*. You then can access the various properties of your desired handle by using the *get()* function. The fields of *h* are the property 'Tag' from each handle. **NOTE:** If 'Tag' is invalid or empty for your uipushbutton, it will not show up in *h*.

When using only one GUI at a time, you can typically write *guihandles(gcf)* instead of explicitly calling the figure handle, but this may not work for your case.

Other than this, I cannot quite tell what you are trying to do with your second GUI.

Comment: This sounds promising. So you are saying putting  all handles of GUI-A to a global variable h? Then how do I call this "h" outside of GUI-A m file?

Comment: I just throw the handles of GUI-A into guihandles and  it works!  Thanks a lot~

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To add to the previous comment, h does not have to be a global variable. Just call guihandles whenever you need it.